# How to do "one shot" time sync using chrony?

Tags: synchronization, clock, ntp

I am looking for an equivalent of 'ntpdate IPaddress' command
in the chrony suite to force chronyd to synchronize time right now.

Comment: You should really check the [documentation...](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.3/chronyd.html)

`chronyd -q`

When run in this mode, chronyd will set the system clock once and exit. It will not detach from the terminal.

Answer (score 65):

Try

```
sudo chronyc -a makestep
```

This will update your system clock quickly (might break some running applications), using the time sources defined in `/etc/chronyd.conf`.

**-a is needed to avoid**

> 501 Not authorised error

Comment: I am getting `501 Not authorised` error returned and clock stays the same

Comment: Are really you running as root (sudo)? You are talking to chronyd, because it sends you away with a rejection. This is covered in the [chrony FAQ](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html#_i_keep_getting_the_error_code_501_not_authorised_code)

Comment: ok, I was running on old server with ubuntu 14.04.5. And chrony version 1.29. I guess there should be some authentication step or smth there...

Comment: Try to run with the `-a` parameter (authenticate automatically)  `sudo chronyc -a makestep`

Comment: The man page for  `chronyc (chrony) version 3.5.1 (+READLINE +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)` (Fedora 32) says the `-a` is ignored.

Answer (score 18):

The chrony equivalent to the `ntpdate SERVER-ADDRESS` command is:

```
    chronyd -q 'server SERVER-ADDRESS iburst'
```

Note that `chronyd` must not be already running, just as `ntpd` must not be running when setting the date with `ntpdate`.

Comment: After that I usually need an additional:
`sudo systemctl start chronyd; sudo chronyc -a 'burst 4/4'
`

Answer (score 11):

In my setup, for various reasons, chronyd is disabled and we want to occasionally manually sync with an NTP server.

For this type of scenario, the command in [Rob Newton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57138113/4469221) is the one that worked (thanks!).

Note that if you are querying the [ntp pool](https://www.ntppool.org/), it is advisable to use the pool command, as in:

```
chronyd -q 'pool pool.ntp.org iburst'
```

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/701371/ntp-conf-pool-vs-server-directives) for additional details.

Also note that if the chronyd service is **not** running, the command `sudo chronyc -a makestep` in [Richard Green's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50341882/4469221) will not work, since it tries to communicate with the chronyd daemon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting:

```
Could not read keyfile or commandkey in file /etc/chrony.conf
```

when running:

```
sudo chronyc -a makestep
```

Then make sure you have the following line in /etc/chrony.conf:

```
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
```

And make sure you have a password for key 0 in /etc/chrony.keys:

```
0 SHA1 HEX:9222248F87B1FDDB01716FC8F1A7B5AB13CDAC91
```

You can generate a SHA1 hashed password:

```
echo -n Th15is4Pa55w0rd! | sha1sum
9222248F87B1FDDB01716FC8F1A7B5AB13CDAC91
```

If that doesn't work, it may be because you have `commandkey` specified as something other than 0 in your /etc/chrony.conf.  The default is 0, so if it's set to something else you need to align it with what's in /etc/chrony.keys.

Comment: I always thought `key 0` means "no key being used".